# ASP.NET Core Web API controller; the LINQ expression could not be translated

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, asp.net-core

I have two SQL Server tables `JobOrders` and `OrderItems`. I would like to retrieve data of each `JobOrders` and order quantity from `OrderItems` in my ASP.NET Core Web API controller.

My two tables and desired result as follows:

**JobOrders**

| Eid | orderID | OrderStatus |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1001 | 1 |
| 2 | 1002 | 5 |
| 3 | 1003 | 3 |

**OrderItems**

| Eid | orderID | OrderStatus | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1001 | abc | 2 |
| 2 | 1001 | adc | 1 |
| 3 | 1002 | jcb | 5 |
| 4 | 1002 | vbb | 2 |
| 5 | 1002 | xyz | 8 |
| 6 | 1003 | akp | 4 |

**Intended Result**

```
[
{
OrderID : 1001,
OrderStatus : 1,
Qty : 3
},
{
OrderID : 1002,
OrderStatus : 5,
Qty : 15
},
{
OrderID : 1003,
OrderStatus : 3,
Qty : 4
}
]
```

This is my controller code:

```
var query = from orders in myDbContext.JobOrders 
            join allorderitems in myDbContext.OrderItems on orders.Eid equals allorderitems.OrderId into orderitems
            from orderitem in orderitems
                 .GroupBy(i => i.OrderId)
                 .Select(g => new
                              {
                                  Qty = g.Sum(i => i.Qty),
                              })
            select new
                   {
                       OrderID = orders.Oid,
                       OrderStatus = orders.Status,
                       Qty = orderitem.Qty,
                   };

var result = query.OrderByDescending(m => m.OrderID).ToList();

return Ok(result);
```

Postman returns:

> 500 Internal Server error:
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.

Comment: Please don't use images for data, use formatted text.

Comment: Are you using EF core? Which version? Please edit the tags of your post if so.

Comment: @Julian EntityFramework 6.4.4

Comment: @DaleK Removed images and and formatted text

Comment: You sure about this bit?

  orders.Eid equals allorderitems.OrderId

Comment: Hi @Sulfy, could you pls share your model design? And have you tried add `AsEnumerable` or `ToList()` anywhere or split the query for multiple steps? Client evaluation has been disabled in EF Core 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `GroupJoin` if you do not plan to do LETF JOIN. It has limited support in EF Core.

```cs
var query = 
    from order in myDbContext.JobOrders 
    join oi in myDbContext.OrderItems on order.Eid equals oi.OrderId
    group oi by new { order.OrderId, order.Status } into g
    select new
    {
        OrderID = g.Key.OrderId,
        OrderStatus = g.Key.Status,
        Qty = g.Sum(x => x.Qty)
    };

var result = query.OrderByDescending(m => m.OrderID).ToList();

return Ok(result);
```

Comment: How do i select a field from JobOrders table?

Comment: With grouping you have access to grouping key and aggregation functions, so add needed field to GroupBy. With EF Core 6, there is possibility to use `g.First().SomeField` but I do not see reason to use it here as it has bad performance. But it needs to change projection of what to group.

Comment: Thank you, I was Stuck on this issue for days